# How to tell if hash's keys are all symbol or string?

Tags: ruby, string, hash, key, symbols

Is there a way to quickly check if the hash as symbols or strings as keys?

Comment: Why do you need to know that? What is the use case? Perhaps any other data structure might be a better choice for your use case?

Comment: Ruby is not a typed language, so you either need to know your data ahead of time, or coerce your values at runtime. Given Hashie or Rails features like HashWithIndifferentAccess, or Struct objects that give you equal access to members with method calls, strings, or symbols, it's hard to guess why this matters. In Ruby, think about coercion or duck-typing rather than object equality for most things and you'll be a lot happier.

Answer (score 3):

### TL;DR

A flat Hash with a single level of keys can easily be interrogated, but nested data structures can't. Additionally, a Hash key isn't limited to just String or Symbol keys. You can use almost any Ruby object as a Hash key, with [a few caveats](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Hash.html#class-Hash-label-User-Defined+Hash+Keys) about what methods the objects must #respond_to? in order to function properly as a key.

### Using #keys.all?

If your Hash isn't a nested data structure, then you could simply ask the Hash if all its top-level keys are Symbol objects:

```
p {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}.keys.all? Symbol
#=> true
```

Just replace `Symbol` with `String` if you want to check the opposite.

However, if you have nested data structures, then you have to iterate over each key and value to symbolize or stringify each key. You can do this with a gem like [Hashie](https://github.com/hashie/hashie), or natively round-trip the Hash to and from JSON to coerce symbols into strings (the default) or perform other object conversions during the serialization or parse. For example, with Ruby 3.1.2:

```
require "json"

hash = {foo: {bar: 1, baz: 2 }}
hash = JSON.parse hash.to_json

hash
#=> {"foo"=>{"bar"=>1, "baz"=>2}}
```

will ensure that all your keys are converted to String objects, or raise an exception if they can't be sensibly converted to a String. You can also pass other [options](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Output+Options) to force different behavior, including support for various [built-in](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Built-in+Additions) or [custom](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-3.1.2/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Custom+JSON+Additions) JSON additions if you want. Round-tripping with YAML or Marshal are also possible, although these are generally less safe than standard JSON if you have tainted or user-provided objects in your Hash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [#all?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) to check whether the hash's keys are all symbols, like so:

```rb
hash = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 }

hash.all? { |key, _value| key.is_a?(Symbol) }
#=> true
```

Comment: But the hash you have above is not symbol based. It is string based. So how is it working?

Comment: The hash in the above example has symbols as keys. That same hash wish string keys would look like this: `{ "foo" => 1, "bar" => 2, "baz" => 3 }`.

Comment: is there no way to check without iteration?

Comment: No there is no other way than iterating over all keys because keys could be any object, a string, a symbol, an integer, a complex object, a class, or anything else. The hash doesn't care and doesn't keep a track of the types of keys stored in the hash. Therefore you need to check all keys.

Comment: Also, keys don't all have to be the same. `{ "foo" => "string", :bar => "symbol", Object.new => "a random object", Object => "a class" }` has keys with different types. There is no place in `Hash` that has an authoritative answer to what its keys are.

Comment: It's admittedly a nitpick, but why assign *\_value* just to throw it away? On a really large Hash, this could have a performance impact, although it probably makes little difference for your example other than being an unnecessary assignment.

Comment: @user2939055 A Ruby Hash is not natively a JSON object. The syntax and the rules for what can be a key or value are very different, although a Hash can generally be serialized to (or parsed from) standard JSON. They aren't the same things, though, which may be creating an X/Y problem for you.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Then again, JSON doesn't have the Symbol type...

Comment: Note that `{}.all? { … }` will always be true - the block returns true for all 0 key-value pairs. This may or may not be what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You may write the following.

```
def key_type(h)
  case h.each_key.map(&:class).uniq
  when [String] then String
  when [Symbol] then Symbol
  else nil
  end
end
```

```
key_type('cats'=>9, 'dogs'=>2)  #=> String
key_type(:cats=>9,  :dogs=>2)   #=> Symbol
key_type('cats'=>9, :dogs=>2)   #=> nil
key_type(:cats=>9, 'dogs'=>2)   #=> nil
key_type(9=>'cats')             #=> nil
key_type(9=>'cats', 2=>'dogs')  #=> nil
key_type({})                    #=> nil
```

For example, if

```
h = { 'cats'=>9, 'dogs'=>2 }
```

then

```
a = h.each_key.map(&:class)
  #=> [String, String]
b = a.uniq
  #=> [String]
```

so `String` is returned. By contrast, if

```
h = { 'cats'=>9, :dogs=>2 }
```

then

```
a = h.each_key.map(&:class)
  #=> [String, Symbol]
b = a.uniq
  #=> [String, Symbol]
```

so `nil` is returned.